# efficiently processing large quantity of files in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing a script and I need to traverse a file system, and return the SHA1 sum of the files.

The code I am using is this:

```
time ruby -r'digest/sha1' -r'find' -e 'Find.find("/") {|x| next unless File.file?(x) ; Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(File.read(x))}
```

The problem is, I get this error message after about 5 seconds after execution

```
-e:1:in `read': failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)
    from -e:1:in `open'
    from -e:1:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/find.rb:43:in `block in find'
    from /usr/share/ruby/find.rb:42:in `catch'
    from /usr/share/ruby/find.rb:42:in `find'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why am I getting this error, and what is the "best practice" for handling a task like this?

Help appreciated.

Comment: How big are these files?

Comment: `File.read` reads the whole contents of a file into memory. If the files might be large, you might need to use `File.open`.

Comment: @Linuxios the basic files which you might find lying around on a *nix filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be well documented (or at least, I'm not looking in the write place) but the Digest library provides a way of hashsumming files by reading the files in chunks and computing the hashsum, versus File.read which reads the whole file into memory.

The working code would be:

```
begin
  Find.find("/") do |file| 
    next unless File.file?(file)
    puts "#{Digest::SHA1.file(file)} #{file}"
  end
rescue => e
  puts e
end
```

Comment: yes that works, also on my 30Gb backupfile although it takes a while 8:), so your solution is cleaner and better, i keep my answer for reference

Answer (score 1):

Why make it difficult by putting this in a one-liner ?
If you put your code in a script like this, on my system everyting runs smooth and every file on my HD is read.
On a data disk you'rd better find a way to handle large files, like the solution at https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/58563 I adapted for SHA1.

```
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'find'


Find.find("/") do |file| 
  next unless File.file?(file)
  begin
    sha = File.open(file, 'rb') do |io|
      dig = Digest::SHA1.new
      buf = ""
      dig.update(buf) while io.read(4096, buf)
      dig
    end
    puts "#{sha} #{file}"
  rescue => e
    puts e.backtrace
  end
end
```

gives

```
ba4aeced8ab461b75ff87d989ff16ca2464ea787 /$AVG/$VAULT/vault.db
31d8730390451d236b80c4351b6b287d6853570c /$AVG/$VAULT/vvfolder.idx
b4c783e3478e5b6f795e92d3cf5d85837fffd128 /$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-50811273-296787125-2640436092-1000/desktop.ini
b4c783e3478e5b6f795e92d3cf5d85837fffd128 /$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-50811273-296787125-2640436092-1011/desktop.ini
3109805dcc447395f58fec8b5e8a8fca1d20892b /.rnd
61fc34796b7cc67caf9da685e59461c9d13fba29 /4nt500/4NT.INI
...
```

Comment: Interesting.   Why the difference between running it in a one-liner (like I did) and running it in a script (like you did)?

Comment: your one liner doesn't run on my system, and I have little experience with them, anyway for testing and maintenance it is better to put it in a script, if necessary you can 'translate' it later to a one-liner, see my modification to rescue in case of an error

Comment: I still end up with a NoMemoryError, even using the code above

Comment: ok, please try my adapted script, it should handle larger files by using a buffer